# How to include a link in the mail message in Struts

Tags: java, email, url, servlets, struts

I am sending a mail after a save is done in DB by using Struts action. Now I need to include a link in the mail which on clicking will hit my action URL.

My dev URL is `wwwdev.sakthi123.road.com`.

my action path will be like

```
wwwdev.sakthi123.road.com/serreqsubmit.do?method=openAssignTo&statusCode='+reqStatus+'&reqId='+reqId;
```

So, from the mail if I click the link I need to hit this path. I need to construct a link in my Action class method while framing the message.

So how do I frame the URL?

I have tried the below:

```java
String eol = System.getProperty("line.separator");   
message ="Please click here "+eol;
message = message + 
          httpServletRequest.getContextPath() +
          "\\serreqsubmit.do?method=openAssignTo&statusCode='+reqStatus+'&reqId='+reqId;";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `<a href=`your link URL here. Construct the URL:

```
String url = "http://" + request.getServerName() + ":" + request.getServerPort()  + request.getContextPath() + "/serreqsubmit.do?method=openAssignTo&statusCode=" + reqStatus + "&reqId=" + reqId;
```

Comment: Yes, and ensure you are sending the mail with mimetype "text/html" instead of "text/plain", to make the link clickable.

Comment: i have used request.getRequestUrl and then appended the query string.But thansk for reminding me to set  mimetype to "text/html".